# Lighthouse - Ensure text remains visible during webfont load - WordPress

Tags: php, css, wordpress, woocommerce, lighthouse

My website is built on WordPress with Elementor. The URL is https://www.montre-connexion.fr.

I'm trying to improve the mobile version to speed it up. But, when I check the site with Lighthouse tool I get this diagnostic:

```
Ensure text remains visible during webfont load
Leverage the font-display CSS feature to ensure text is user-visible while webfonts are loading.
```

Then, it shows the following URL: https://www.montre-connexion.fr/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/assets/fonts/star.woff

It seems the problem is from WooCommerce plugin. So, I've tried to add `font-display:swap` in the plugin `CSS` file where there is `@font-face`. However, it doesn't work.

Besides, I've tried a lot of solutions that I've found on the internet, like this website https://web.dev/font-display/, but I haven't found the solution yet. I've installed some plugins as well, but no result.

Could you please give me the solution?

Comment: You did not answer to the question?!

Comment: My question is on-topic!

Comment: I deleted this part of the question. Basically, I said that I've tried myself but didn't get the solution. So my question is on-topic!

Comment: _"Is there any php code to insert or some good plugin?"_ - Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, plugin, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.

Comment: I've deleted this part of the question as well. But, it doesn't matter. I just want to find a solution to speed up my website.

Comment: Your website takes 8 to 9 seconds to load, has a 2MB stylesheet and your largest Javascript file is 400kb. The html is a hefty 400kb and your homepage weighs 5MB. I do not think that you should focus on font loading. Focus on getting those numbers down.